# Failed 12.04 installation on W7 Machine, how do I resolve this?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, korean

I successfully installed 12.04 with wubi on a Windows 7 machine. but after a restart, remaining installation process failed to work.

About 2/3rds of the installation had completed..

How can I solve it?

Comment: What graphics card do you have? What happened during the 2nd phase install? Freeze? Error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have DVD or USB for installation then try to reinstall ubuntu form windows wubi installer and when PC is restart , select ubuntu and it will take approx 1/2 hours for complete installation and disconnect the internet.

If you are installing using powere iso or other disk image, then make it bootable at startup.

**** " your installation DVD/USB should not have any error or missing files"